# Select specific duplicate database values and display the count

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, where-clause

I've tried a million different ways, and this is probably something super simple, but I can't get it figured out.

I have a database that displays several different columns (name, age, gender, breed, player, etc.)

What I would like is to include a line that states "We have ___ number of female characters."

Here is my entire page where I want it displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>AUSUS --- mythical equine RPG</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/evolution2.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn:400,400italic,700,700italic|Kreon:400,700,300|La+Belle+Aurore|Stalemate|IM+Fell+English:400,400italic|Mrs+Saint+Delafield' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Character Database</h1>


<p>
We currently have <b>

<?php

$link = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***");
mysql_select_db("tarb89_characters", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows";

?>

</b>
characters listed in the database.  You may search the character database by character name or player name.  Dams and sires marked with an asterisk (*) are from <b>outside</b> Ausus.<br><br>




 <br><br>
<form action="searchchars.php" method="GET"/>
<input type="text" name="searchchars" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Character Name Search" /><br>
</form>
<br>
<form action="searchplays.php" method="GET"/>
<input type="text" name="searchplays" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Player Name Search" />
</form>
</p>

<p>
<br><br>
<?php
/// In order to use this script freely
/// you must leave the following copyright
/// information in this file:
/// Copyright 2012 www.turningturnip.co.uk
/// All rights reserved.

include("connect.php");

if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20");
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);

if ($num > 0 ) {
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$id = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"id"));
$name = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"name"));
    $breed = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"breed"));
    $gender = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"gender"));
    $color = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"color"));
    $markings = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"markings"));
    $genetics = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"genetics"));
    $player = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"player"));
    $traits = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"traits"));
    $defects = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"defects"));
    $extras = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"extras"));
    $profile = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"profile"));
    $dam = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"dam"));
    $sire = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"sire"));
    $status = stripslashes(mysql_result($result,$i,"status"));

$row .= '

<h5>'.$name.'</h5>

<table width="550px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="20" style="background: #eeeeee; border-radius: 15px; border: 1px solid #5067be;">
<tr>
<td width="50%"><p>
    <b>ID Number:</b>  '.$id.'<br>
    <b>Breed:</b>  '.$breed.'<br>
    <b>Gender:</b>  '.$gender.'<br>
    <b>Dam:  </b>'.$dam.'<br>
    <b>Sire:  </b>'.$sire.'<br>
    <b>Status:  </b>'.$status.'<br>
    <b>Profile:</b>  <a href="'.$profile.'">Click Here</a><br>
    <b>Player:</b>  '.$player.'</p></td>
<td width="50%"><p>        
    <b>Color:</b>  '.$color.'<br>
    <b>Genetics: </b>'.$genetics.'<br>
    <b>Markings:</b>  '.$markings.'<br>
    <b>Traits:</b>  '.$traits.'<br>
    <b>Defects:</b>  '.$defects.'<br>
    <b>Extras:</b>  '.$extras.'</p></td>
    </table><br>

    ';






++$i; }} else { $row = '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Database empty.</td></tr>'; }

mysql_close();
?>

<? echo $row ?>
</p><center>
<font face="tahoma" style="font-size: 12px;">Pages: 
<?php
include("connect.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(name) FROM characters");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20);

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
        echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> | ";
};
?>
</center></font> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your query `SELECT SUM(gender='female') FROM characters GROUP BY gender` and no of females `echo $num_rows;`

Comment: You really should remove your db username and password, very bad idea to post it on here.

Comment: Use [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_num_rows) --- That's what I use for a similar application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example for the same you can edit this

```
<?php
$cnt = 0;
$query = "select * from table";
$resulr = mysql_query($query);
while($var = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  if($var['gender']=='female'){
    $cnt++;
  }
}
echo "We have ".$cnt." female characters";
?>
```

Comment: What you are doing here is making the PHP code do something that could be done more efficiently (and probably faster) by the database management system. Why is that? And why are you doing it with such an inefficient query - if you only need to look at gender why "select *"?

Comment: But in case if he want to use another details from same table then its easy to use for him

Comment: In that case, he can add the fields he needs into the query when and if he needs them. The table might be huge and the extra fields you are asking for might take a long time to load. Generally, this is not a good practice.

Comment: yes it is possible :) here i am also for learning new things.  it was one of them. thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM characters where gender = 'female'
```

That will get you the count of characters which have 'female' as the value for gender. Is that what you want?